# Error getting listview column names

Tags: vb.net

When I use a loop to get the list view columns names, I am getting an error as shown below.

This is my loop:

```
For xCnt = 2 To lvHolidays.Columns.Count
            strState = lvHolidays.Columns(xCnt).Text
            For Each li In fHoliday.lvStates.Items
                If strState = li.Text Then
                    If lvHolidays.SelectedItems(xCnt).SubItems(xCnt - 1).Text = "Yes" Then
                        li.Checked = True
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

This is the error:

```
"InvalidArgument=Value of '18' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
For xCnt = 2 To lvHolidays.Columns.Count-1
```

Comment: In my List View I have 18 columns, and i want to get after 2 column

Comment: Yes. But count starts at 0 so last index is Count-1. Say you have 10 columns. First column is 0 last would then be 9. 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 <- Count of 10. So index for last column is 9 but it will be the 10th column.